What is the memory address for 24AA16 EEPROM IC?
I am using 24AA16 EEPROM IC to read and write. But i don't know exactly the memory adddress to write something in this IC and also read from that. This is the datasheet for this IC,
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/24AA16-24LC16B-24FC16-16K-I2C-Serial-EEPROM-20001703P.pdf
This is my sample code to write,
w = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, EEPROM_ADDRESS, 0x0000, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT, data_write, EEPROM_PAGESIZE, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

Here i write something in address 0x0000. If i read my data from  0x0010 means then also it reads my data. But i wrote my data in 0x0000 address. Can you understand my question? This is what exactly happen. Can anyone tell me what is the correct memory address to write and read?

Did you read a datasheet ?  Take a look at Figure 5-2, there you can see that this memory have 8bit address size (+3 bits in I2C slave address). But you are using function for 16bit addressing (I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_16BIT) !

I already answered in your previous question what the problem in the code is and you are still use wrong code that is unfixed. If you did not understand the answer, put a comment there. This is essentially a duplicate of your previous question, just worded differently.

@Kuralmozhi So I suggest you delete this and focus on understanding answers you already have. The HAL will work if you just use it correctly.

I write my data in 0x00 address, for example my data is “testing”. my written data stored like this,
0th address - t,
1st address - e,
2nd address - s,
3rd address - t,
4th address - i,
5th address - n,
6th address - g.
Now I write a new data “result” in 0x03 address means,
0 to 2 address “t”, “e”, “s”,
From 3 “result” will be written.
My doubt is from 0 to 2 “t”, “e”, “s” will be erased or stored?
